# Generic multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T, int dimension = 1>
class Array
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> pointer;
    int size[dimension];
    int realSize;

public:
    Array()
    {
    }

    template<typename... Ns>
    Array(Ns... ns)
    : realSize(1)
    {
        create(1, ns...);
    }

private:
    template<typename... Ns>
    void create(int d, int n, Ns... ns)
    {
        realSize *= n;
        size[d - 1] = n;
        create(d + 1, ns...);
    }

    void create(int d)
    {
        pointer = std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[realSize]);
    }

    int computeSubSize(int d) const
    {
        if (d == dimension)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return size[d] * computeSubSize(d + 1);
    }

    template<typename... Ns>
    int getIndex(int d, int n, Ns... ns) const
    {
        return n * computeSubSize(d) + getIndex(d + 1, ns...);
    }

    int getIndex(int d) const
    {
        return 0;
    }

public:
    template<typename... Ns>
    T& operator()(Ns... ns) const
    {
        return pointer[getIndex(1, ns...)];
    }

    int getSize(int d = 1) const
    {
        return size[d - 1];
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 10;
    Array<int> a(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.getSize(); ++i)
    {
        a(i) = i + 1;
        cout << a(i) << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n' << endl;
    Array<int, 2> a2(N, N * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < a2.getSize(1); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a2.getSize(2); ++j)
        {
            a2(i, j) = i + j + 2;
            if (a2(i, j) < 10)
            {
                cout << '0';
            }
            cout << a2(i, j) << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
>
> 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
> 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
> 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
> 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
> 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
> 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
> 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
> 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
> 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
> 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
> ```

Comment: `int size[dimension];` - isn't this just the number of elements in a single-dimensional array?

Comment: @Jamal Yes it is.

Comment: Then I don't understand the variable `dimension` here.

Comment: @Jamal It is the number of dimensions for the array. 1 for 1D, 2 for 2D, 3 for 3D and so on.

Comment: @Jamal In a single-dimensional array, yes `size[dimension]` is just the number of elements, but in an n-dimensional array where n > 1, it stores the size for each dimension.

Answer (score 8):

- No need for an empty constructor in C++11:

  > ```
  > Array()
  > {
  > }
  > ```

  You can just use a [`default` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

  ```
  Array() = default;
  ```
- It's a little confusing to have multiple `public`/`private` sections.  Here, you can just put all the `public` code under the same keyword.
- You could make your structure more useful by providing iterators.  This will, for instance, allow you to use range based `for`-loops instead of plain ones for iterating through this structure.
- You don't need `std::endl` if you just need newlines.  Just output `"\n"` instead for this.  More info about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).
- It's unnecessary to have your own `return 0` at the end of `main()` in C++.  The compiler will provide this return for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things :

- Naming your variables. I don't know why, the naming of your functions is quite good, but not the naming of your variables, why ? `a`, `n`, `i`, `d`, among others, deserve to have a real name, for readability.
- `if (a2(i, j) < 10)` I see what you're doing here but please don't do it that way. Using `std::setfill` and `std::setw` could do that for you. Or a good old `printf`
- `for (int i = 0; i < a2.getSize(1); ++i)` Is the size of *a2* going to change inside the loop ? If not, there's no need to compute at each loop iteration.
- Not a single comment in all your code, that's a performance, but not a good one. If you want to make up for this, you could even use Doxygen-style comments, to be able to generate quickly some documentation, in addition to normal comments inside your complicated functions.
- `cout << '\n' << endl;` Not quite sure what you want to do there.

Answer (score 2):

For your `int` template parameter, it makes no sense to have a *signed* dimension quantity. Use `size_t` as that parameter and update `int` to `size_t` in your code.