# Dynamic multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, array, template-meta-programming

My application needs `Field` objects, which encapsulate 1D, 2D or 3D gridded data. The number of dimensions and their size are known only at run time. Furthermore, I need the encapsulated data to be in one contiguous memory block for performance reasons.

I've based my code on the [following code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94148/generic-multidimensional-array-in-c), which defines simple multidimensional arrays using meta-programming / variadic templates. Those arrays need to know their number of dimensions at compile-time. Therefore my object `Field`, being limited to 1D, 2D and 3D cases, encapsulate three of those arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


template<typename T, int dimension = 1>
class Array
{


public:
    Array() = default;


    template<typename... Sizes>
    Array(Sizes... sizes)
    : linearSize_(1)
    {
        allocate(1, sizes...);
    }


    template<typename... Ns>
    inline T& operator()(Ns... ns) //const
    {
        return data_[getIndex(1, ns...)];
    }



    template<typename... Ns>
    inline T operator()(Ns... ns) const
    {
        return data_[getIndex(1, ns...)];   
    } 



    int getSize(int dim = 1) const //dim == 1,2 or 3
    {
        if (dim < 1 || dim > 3)
            throw(std::runtime_error("invalid dimension"));
        else
            return dimSize_[dim - 1];
    }



private:
    std::vector<T> data_;
    int dimSize_[dimension];
    int linearSize_;


    // -------------------

    // allocate memory for variable dimension array
    template<typename... dimSizes>
    void allocate(int dim, int dimsize, dimSizes... dimsizes)
    {
        linearSize_ *= dimsize;
        dimSize_[dim - 1] = dimsize;
        allocate(dim + 1, dimsizes...);
    }

    void allocate(int dim) // end recursion and allocate memory
    {
        data_.resize(linearSize_);
    }

    // -------------------


    int computeSubSize(int dim) const
    {
        if (dim == dimension)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return dimSize_[dim] * computeSubSize(dim + 1);
    }



    template<typename... DimSizes>
    int getIndex(int dim, int dimsize, DimSizes... dimsizes) const
    {
        return dimsize * computeSubSize(dim) + getIndex(dim + 1, dimsizes...);
    }

    int getIndex(int dim) const // end recursion
    {
        return 0;
    }


};




class Field
{
    private:
        Array<double,1> data1D;
        Array<double,2> data2D; 
        Array<double,3> data3D; 


    public:
        Field(std::size_t size):data1D{size}
        {std::cout << "1D\n";}

        Field(std::size_t size1, std::size_t size2)
        :data2D{size1, size2}
        {
            std::cout << "2D\n";
        }

        Field(std::size_t size1, std::size_t size2, std::size_t size3)
        : data3D(size1, size2, size3)
        {
            std::cout << "3D\n";
            std::cout << "array size = (" 
                      <<  data3D.getSize()
                      << ","
                      << data3D.getSize(2)
                      << ","
                      << data3D.getSize(3)
                      << ")"
                      << std::endl;
        }

        inline double& operator()(unsigned int i)
        {
            return data1D(i);
        }

        inline double& operator()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j)
        {
            return data2D(i,j); 
        }

        inline double& operator()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j, unsigned int k)
        {
            return data3D(i,j,k);   
        }

};




int main()
{ 
    int nx,ny,nz;
    nx= 20;
    ny=200;
    nz=33;

    Field f1(nx);
    Field f2(nx,ny);
    Field f3(nx,ny,nz); 

    f2(19,30) = 3;
    std::cout << f2(19,30) << "\n";


}
```

The wandbox compile/run online version is [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VvSUh3IsvQIZTkdz#wandbox-resultwindow-code-body-4).

What I like here is that there are no pointers, memory is allocated and deleted when needed. The user just uses the Field object by value.

However I'm not a huge fan of defining all three operators the way I did. I trust the user not to do:

```
Field f(100);
f(2,2) = 30; // try to access the non allocated data2D...
```

Is there a way to make something similar and safer?

Comment: Can you comment why you think you had to limit the `dimension` of `Array` to 3? I'm also not sure what you mean by “safer”. I guess you will already have thought yourself of the option to add a run-time check so I'm not sure what to say about this.

Comment: 3 as in 3 dimensions of space. This is for simulation purposes... we can do 1D, 2D or 3D simulations, but no need for more.

Comment: Regarding the safety. I thought about adding a test in the operator yes but I don't want to pay that cost when 99.99% of the time it will pass no problem. What I meant is maybe encapsulating the 3 `Array`s like this is not the best idea... for instance one may Have an `Field1D`, `Field2D`, `Field3D` inheriting from abstract `Field`and each having its own array....  but then the syntax to call the operator becomes ugly like e.g. : I need to cast my `Field` to `Field2D` and do (*Field2D)(i,j)... Was wondering whether another solution was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't defer to run-time what you can check at compile-time

When I started playing with your `Array`, I kept getting weird segfaults until I realized that I had forgotten to set the second `template` parameter correctly. This is something your constructor could easily check at compile-time with no overhead.

```
template <typename... Sizes>
Array(Sizes... sizes) : linearSize_(1)
{
  static_assert(sizeof...(sizes) == Dimensions, "wrong number of size arguments");
  allocate(1, sizes...);
}
```

Likewise for `operator()`:

```
template <typename... Ns>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Ns) == Dimensions), T&>::type
operator()(Ns... ns)
{
  const auto idx = getIndex(1, ns...);
  return data_[idx];
}
```

> **C++14**:
>
> Your question is tagged [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) but if you can use C++14, you can replace
>
> ```
> typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Ns) == Dimensions), T&>::type
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Ns) == Dimensions), T&>
> ```
>
> which will do the exact same thing but look far less intimidating.

Note that I have taken the liberty to rename your `dimension` non-type `template` parameter to `Dimensions`. I found the singular very confusing and ambiguous with other usages of the term “dimension” in the code. I'd also recommend that you make it a habit to use CamelCase names for `template` parameters to distinguish them from other variables.

#### Avoid arbitrary restrictions

You've commented that your application currently only needs multi-dimensional arrays of at most 3 dimensions. This is fine but no reason to arbitrarily restrict your `Array` if it doesn't make its implementation easier. The only place where you refer to the limit is inside `getSize` and there the restriction shows up in the least helpful way. Your code actually *allows* me to create an `Array<T, 42>` but when I ask for the size of the 5<sup>th</sup> dimension, it will crash at run-time. On the other hand, asking for the size of the 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension of a 2-dimensional `Array` won't be caught and invoke undefined behavior.

What you should do instead is check `getSize`'s argument against the actual number of dimensions of the `Array`.

```
int getSize(int dim = 1) const
{
  if (dim < 1 || dim > Dimensions)
    throw(std::runtime_error("invalid dimension"));
  else
    return dimSize_[dim - 1];
}
```

But I have more to say about this function later…

If you really need to restrict the maximum number of dimensions of an `Array`, do it statically at `class` scope. However, instead of disallowing more than 3 dimensions, I'd rather enforce it has at least 1.

```
template <typename T, int Dimensions>
class Array
{
  static_assert(Dimensions >= 1, "Array must have at least 1 dimension");

  // …
};
```

#### Use 0-based indexing

It really confused me that `getSize` expects 1-based indexing of dimensions. This choice also makes your implementation more complicated because now you have to internally map the indices back to 0-based indices for subscripting the `dimSize_` array.

#### Avoid non-intuitive default parameters

Defaulting parameters to reasonable default values can help making your interfaces easier to use. However, if the default is non-obvious, it makes the interface more confusing and hides bugs. For example, I don't see why `getSize` should give me the size of the first dimension if I forget to specify one. Likewise, what justifies defaulting the number of dimensions of the `Array` to 1? If the default isn't obvious, I'd embrace the guideline that *“explicit is better than implicit”*.

#### Consider a re-design of `Array::getSize`

Combining some of the above thoughts, I would recommend a re-design of `getSize`. Zeroth, change the index to be 0-based. First, I would make the function a `template` that takes no arguments and a non-type `template` parameter for the dimension instead. Once you do this, you can statically check the dimension (against the actual number of dimensions).

```
template <int Dim>
typename std::enable_if<(Dim >= 0) && (Dim < Dimensions), int>::type
getSize() const noexcept
{
  return dimSize_[Dim];
}
```

Now we could offer an overload that `return`s the total number of elements in the `Array` which might be useful sometimes.

```
int
getSize() const noexcept
{
  return static_cast<int>(data_.size());
}
```

#### Consider using `std::size_t` for indices

Note the ugly `static_cast` in the above snippet? Some people make a point that it was a mistake to use `unsigned` types for array dimensions and indices but its use is now so prevalent that converting back and forth generally causes more trouble than it does good.

#### The `linearSize_` member of `Array` is redundant

See the above implementation of `getSize`. The `std::vector` already knows how big it is.

#### `Array::operator()` should always `return` a reference

I'd be consistent with the standard library containers and always `return` a reference from subscripting functions (also the `const` overloads). If `T == int` or a similar cheaply copyable type, it doesn't really matter but people might also want to put `std::string`s or other expensive types into your `Array`. Since your implementation is based on `std::vector` and the latter always `return`s a reference anyway, simply passing it thorough doesn't cost you anything extra.

#### Make `Array` a container

I think your `Array` would be significantly more useful if it would model the [`Container`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) concept from the standard library. You can look the exact requirements up yourself. Suffice to say that implementing them would for the most part be an exercise of simply delegating to the underlying `std::vector`.  For example:

```
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator
begin() const { return data_.begin(); }

typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator
end() const { return data_.end(); }
```

> **C++14:**
>
> In C++14, you can replace the tedious `typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator` with simply `auto`.

Note how this matches with the earlier suggestion of adding a `getSize` member function that takes no arguments and `return`s the total number of elements in the `Array`. You would have to rename it to `size` to be standards-compliant, of course.

Being able to iterate the elements of your multi-dimensional array in sequential order could be a huge performance gain for algorithms like adding two `Array`s (of equal dimensions) element-wise. Instead of repetitively mapping tuples of indices to offsets in the linear array, we could simply iterate over the linear memory in one blast. Not to mention that we wouldn't have to do this ourselves but could leverage the standard library algorithms.

#### Consider exposing allocator support

All standard library containers that dynamically allocate memory are customizable via an additional `template` parameter `AllocatorT` that defaults to [`std::allocator<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) which simply calls the global `new` and `delete`. While the allocator interface is a little clumsy, supporting this customization would be very easy in your case since all you'd have to do is pass the allocator on to the `std::vector`.

```
template
<
  typename T,
  std::size_t Dimensions,
  typename AllocatorT = std::allocator<T>
>
class Array
{
  static_assert((Dimensions >= 1), "...");

public:

  Array() = default;

  Array(const AllocatorT& alloc) : data_(alloc) { }

  template <typename... SizeTs>
  Array(SizeTs... sizes)
  {
    static_assert((sizeof...(SizeTs) == Dimensions), "...");
    resize(sizes...);
  }

  template <typename... SizeTs>
  typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(SizeTs) == Dimensions)>::type
  resize(SizeTs... sizes);

  // …

private:

  std::array<std::size_t, Dimensions> dimSize_;
  std::vector<T, AllocatorT> data_;

  // …

};


template <typename T, std::size_t Dimensions, typename AllocatorT>
template <typename... SizeTs>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(SizeTs) == Dimensions)>::type
Array<T, Dimensions, AllocatorT>::resize(SizeTs... sizes)
{
  // If you want to be very careful, check that the sizes can be converted to
  // std::size_t without loss.
  const std::array<std::size_t, Dimensions> dimsize = {{ std::size_t(sizes)... }};
  const auto newsize = std::accumulate(std::begin(dimsize), std::end(dimsize),
                                       std::size_t {1},
                                       std::multiplies<std::size_t> {});
  dimSize_.fill(0);
  data_.resize(newsize);
  dimSize_ = dimsize;
}
```

Since there is no clean way to accept an additional allocator argument in the constructor that takes the dimensions as variable `template` parameter pack, you'll probably want to add a `resize` member function so you can first construct an empty `Array` with a supplied allocator (if the default-constructed allocator is not good enough) and then resize it afterwards.

Why am I taking the allocator by `const`-reference and not by value? Maybe because the standard library containers make the same mistake.

> **C++14:**
>
> In C++14 you can use [`std::multiplies<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies) instead of `std::multiplies<T>` which is *so much better*.

#### Consider iteration instead of recursion

Recursion is often said to be elegant but I doubt that it adds net gain in this case. On the contrary, the recursive implementations of `getIndex` and `computeSubSize` rather confused me.

For comparison, I'll show you an iterative approach from the implementation of a multi-dimensional array `class` I once wrote myself.

```
// This is a private helper function
template <typename... Indices>
std::size_t
position_(Indices... idcs) const
{
  const std::array<std::size_t, Dims> indices = {{idcs...}};
  assert(this->indices_valid_(indices));
  auto pos = std::size_t {indices[0]};
  for (auto dim = std::size_t {1}; dim < Dims; ++dim)
    pos = pos * this->extents_[dim] + indices[dim];
  return pos;
}
```

`Dims` is the equivalent of your `dimension` and `extents_` is what you call `dimSize_`.

#### Offer bounds-checking for indexing

Subscription errors in multi-dimensional arrays are hard to debug. For example, if you accidentally swap two indices, chances are high that you still land within a valid index of the backing `std::vector` so no amount of “debug-STL” will help you there. Notice the `assert` in the code above? The function `indices_valid_` is implemented like this.

```
// This is a private helper function
bool
indices_valid_(const std::array<std::size_t, Dims>& indices) const noexcept
{
  for (auto dim = std::size_t {}; dim < Dims; ++dim)
    {
      if (indices[dim] >= this->extents_[dim])
        return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

If the code is compiled with `-DNDEBUG`, the `assert` and all associated overhead will go away.

#### Redundant `inline`s

You don't have to declare `template`s as `inline`, that's implicit. In the same way, functions defined inside the `class` body are also implicitly `inline`.

#### Random thoughts about the `Field`…

I'm not sure I can say many useful things about the `Field` `class` `template`. My first thought is: Do you really need this type? I'm having a hard time thinking of an algorithm that can work on arrays of different numbers of dimensions. It seems likely to me that you could refactor your application such that the number of dimensions are always known statically. I'd have to know more about your application to say more about this, of course.

Assuming you really need to make the number of dimensions a run-time value, there is not much that static type-checking can do for you. You'll have to implement your own dynamic checking that can at best terminate your program if it detects a bug. I recommend you use `assert` again for this. It has the correct semantics and users can disable the checking in favor of more speed in already-debugged builds.

It also irks me a little that there are always three `Array` members inside `Field` only one of which will be valid at any time. You could consider using a `union` or `boost::variant` to reduce the size of the `Field`.

What I would not do is using polymorphism through inheritance and `virtual` functions. It seems unlikely to me that it will make the code easier to use and will probably add the highest overhead.

A final thought would be to always use an `Array<double, 3>` but set the first dimension to 1 if the data is actually only 2-dimensional and likewise for 1-dimensional data.

Comment: I need the field to have a dimensionality known at runtime so static is not good. However the idea of having just the threeD and use only one or two dimensions for 1D and 2D cases deserves some thought!!

Thanks also so much for your very detailed review. Very much appreciated!